# Get first matching ancestor containing a specific class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, closest, parents

I am trying to iterate to the first ancestor containing the class ‘sys-form-row’.

I am able to get the row containing class="sys-form-row" using the following: objBack =

```
$('#txtMyBox2').parent().parent();
```

This seems incredibly clumsy.  What I would like to do is something like this:

`$('#txtMyBox2').parents('.sys-form-row');`  or even `$('#txtMyBox2').closest('.sys-form-row');` however both fail and my current approach will not always work if additional div nesting is applied.
Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: or beter create a jsfiddle.net

Comment: I am new to this and each toime I post markup it becomes part of the page.

Comment: The `closest` example should be the correct way to do this. As Shankar says, we need to see your HTML code.

Comment: @user831839 Select the code you want to show and press the icon with the two curly brackets `{}` above the text box. This will format the content as code.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If the additional nested div has any specific class you can use closest to find the parent

```
//It will always give you the closest element having class ".sys-form-row"
$('#txtMyBox2').closest(".sys-form-row");
```

Comment: still testing.  Will get back.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who responded.

Comment: Silly name for a function, it should be named ancestor, firstAncester or closestAncester. There's nothing in its name to indicate the DOM traversal is in the `up` direction.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$("#txtMyBox2").parents(".sys-form-row:first");
```

Comment: In my case closest was also giving 2 elemments, this works perfectly